# What result from REST endpoint is more common?

Tags: json, rest, architecture

We are during design of our REST-API and we are wondering in what form REST endpoint should return data?
We have an endpoint that returns so-called "identity" objects that have different attributes.
Each 'identities' has unique string  eg. UUID#cf684c35-200e-4936-8b63-e6e51b6e3569.

We are wondering which format the developers are more used to?
Like this below:

```
{
  "UUID#cf684c35-200e-4936-8b63-e6e51b6e3569": {
    "validity_date": 1608591121,
    "visibility": "private"
  },
  "RFID#cf684c35-200e-4936-8b63-e6e51b6e3570": {
    "validity_date": 1608591123,
    "visibility": "public".
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "identity": "UUID#cf684c35-200e-4936-8b63-e6e51b6e3569",
      "validity_date": 1608591121,
      "visibility": "private"
    },
    {
      "identity": "RFID#cf684c35-200e-4936-8b63-e6e51b6e3570",
      "validity_date": 0,
      "visibility": "1608591123"
    },
  ]
}
```

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** I recommend to use a list of objects (your second approach).

Let's take your objects to a more obvious example of users with an `id` and a `name`:

```json
{
  1: {
    "name": "Michal"
  },
  2: {
    "name": "Thomas"
  }
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Michal"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Thomas"
  }
]
```

Both approaches can be used, I don't see any difference from the API-level itself.

But let's consider how an application might provide or consume such data:

- fetching a database table of users (e.g. whose birthday is next week)
- showing a table of users (e.g. user name and birthday)
- processing the monthly salary to employees

All three examples use a list of users, which is the second approach. Since many applications operate on a list of entities, that's a common sense for APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it `[]` is better than it `{ "results": [] }`.

Said it, on my opinion the 2nd is better because of [on some languages] is easier to map it than to map the 1st.